# AWS Application Load Balancer throws net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, load-balancing

I have created an microservice API application and hosted it on AWS ECS cluster and attached this cluster to AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB). Added a certificate from AWS Certificate Manager to the ALB. When I try to call using the link provided by AWS ALB, from my frontend app, it returns an error:

net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

The link from ALB is sonething like this:
xxxxx-xx-xxxxxxxxx.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com

I attached a SSL certificate to the listener. The SSL is issued using AWS Certificate Manager for my-site.xyz and *.my-site.xyz

The frontend application is react application hosted on different-site.ai using AWS Amplify

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**
The OP wanted this to resolve for their root/apex domain `example.com`, as they use Namecheap (which support an Alias record) a value was added for the root domain following [these instructions](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10128/2237/how-to-create-an-alias-record).

Alias records are also supported in Route 53.

It needed to be an alias record as a root domain traditionally can only resolve to an IP address which would be an `A` record, whereas Alias will map the IP of the CNAME record to the value instead.

**Original**

The error thrown is because the SSL certificate that is attached is not applicable for the domain you're trying to access.

For example the cert is for `example.com` but you're trying to access `xxxxx-xx-xxxxxxxxx.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com`.

To access this you must access on a valid domain name, to do this add a DNS record so that `example.com` resolves to `xxxxx-xx-xxxxxxxxx.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com`. Then when accessing `example.com` the SSL will be valid.

Comment: Can you please explain how do I add a DNS record that resolves to xxxxx-xx-xxxxxxxxx.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com.. If this works, I'll upvote all your answers

Comment: Did you managed to get it? If not tell me your hosting provider and I'll try to find some docs for it :)

Comment: my hosting provider is namecheap.com , I need to know what values to put in and what kind of record to make

Comment: OK is your domain the Apex record (`example.com`) or Subdomain (`subdomain.example.com`)?

Comment: It is example.com

Comment: OK great, so you'd want to follow: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10128/2237/how-to-create-an-alias-record. Add an Alias record of `@` with the value of `xxxxx-xx-xxxxxxxxx.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Did that. Let me wait for 5 minutes and see if it works

Comment: It is working :D Please update in the answer for others that an Alias with Host as @ and value as the load balancer link needs to be created. Awesome. Thanks

Comment: Updated answer :)

Comment: Thanks for this. A bit off topic, but my issue was with a custom domain on an API Gateway. Make sure you map your DNS record to the API Gateway's domain name, not its invoke URL.

Comment: I have the same issue, but I'm using Route53 as my DNS table. I added an A alias record to my ALB (for example.com), and a CNAME to the same ALB (for www.example.com). Then requested a SSL cert and included both example.com and www.example.com. And I'm getting net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when I was requesting a certificate, I failed to list the domain names correctly.

For example, if your website was *`www.somewhere.com`*, you would need to add

```
www.somewhere.com
```

and also add

```
somewhere.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The key for me was Route 53 - The A record should NOT point to any hardcoded IPs, but instead should be an **Alias to an ALB / Classic Load Balancer**.

(Edit the Route 53 record - choose your exact ALB from the dropdown list), and it will fill the 'URL' : dualstack.alb-123456.us-region.elb.amazonaws.com

Followed this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html